# Equivalent of private variable (leading underscore) in es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I have this code here:

```
  getData(value, index) {
    const {responseMetadata, responseData} = this.getResponseDatum();
    return responseData.get(index).get('code').toUpperCase();
  }
```

`eslint` reports an error:

```
  19:12  "responseMetadata" is defined but never used
```

In python I can silent this kind of error by renaming the variable to `_responseMetadata`. Is there a Equivalent in es6?

Comment: why do you need to define it if it's not being used? it's not an error in JS to have unused stuff...

Comment: It is the function signature of `getResponseDatum` which returns a dictionary as such. You have to accept sometimes we can't change some APIs at will.

Comment: the signature doesn't need to be filled out  `const responseData = this.getResponseDatum().responseData;` and `const {responseData} = this.getResponseDatum();` both work...

Comment: Please turn it into an answer and I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: FWIW, this has nothing to do with ES6. That completely depends on how configurable eslint is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the variable, just don't create it:

```
const {responseData} = this.getResponseDatum();
```

A destructuring assignment doesn't need to match all properties of the returned object.

In your case, since you need only one property and don't use it multiple times, there's actually not much reason to use destructuring or a variable at all:

```
getData(value, index) {
    return this.getResponseDatum().responseData.get(index).get('code').toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off a rule for a section of code. See http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#configuring-rules

```
/*eslint-disable */

//suppress all warnings between comments
alert('foo');

/*eslint-enable */
```